# Copy and paste not working in remote desktop session on window 19

Tags: window, copy-paste, rdp

Only one window user on window 19 standard server is not able to copy (clip copy and paste)  after login on the remote desktop session.
Other  users are able to copy and paste the text and image  from local machine to remote  desktop  server, except one user.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Windows 19?????

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved just restart rdpclic.exe